# What decides that a light will excite something?

Tags: visible-light, scattering

Are there any conditions on when an absorption and reemission process will happen Are the atoms in my bottle getting excited and re-emitting the light bouncing around in my well lit room?

Irrespective of the kind of substance things in my room are made of there is some sort of absorption and remission process going on I think which helps us see the things.

So when I see a red ball I am guessing the red light is scattered more dominantly than others.

A single atom scenario is simple. For the case of hydrogen, the expectation value of the dipole operator gives us all the information about this re-emission process.

But are there conditions that derermine when an excitation or emission will take place for many body things?

Comment: There are many ways light interacts with matter. Reflection, refraction, scattering (many varieties), fluorescence, phosphorescence, superradiance, ...

Comment: "Many body things" , interactions light, are very accurately described by the classical electrodynamics of Maxwell's equations. Excitation and emission belong to quantum electrodynamics . The classical emerges from the quantum one, but the classical is enough to describe light in a room.

Comment: @JohnDoty And are all of those things happening to all the objects of the my room? I am guessing then besides relfection (which makes me see the object) all other processes emit light in invisible region?

Comment: Well, in this room, light is refracted by the windows (very noticeable in hundred year old flattened cylinder sheet glass), the translucent lampshades scatter light, some of the bulbs are fluorescent, there are phosphorescent treads on the stairs around the corner, and there a couple of OLED screens (which I believe have some superradiance going on).